# Arduino Errors with sainsmart sheild

Tags: ide, arduino, lcd

http://pastebin.com/86JXkUBf

This is my Arduino code that I am using as a status indicator for me and my roommate.  The code as working completely fine until I decided to be able to edit the first line on the display, which is the sainsmart LCD keypad shield.  Now, when I verify the code in the arduino IDE, i get the following set of errors:

```
sketch_jul22b.cpp:15:81: error: expected unqualified-id before '\x593a'
sketch_jul22b.cpp:15:81: error: expected ‘}’ before '\x593a'
sketch_jul22b.cpp:15:81: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before '\x593a'
sketch_jul22b.cpp:15:88: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

I would appreciate it very much if somebody would tell me:
1) what these errors mean.
2) How to resolve them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrected code that compiles.
http://pastebin.com/j5B37UUP
@praks411 was correct, but there were some typo's and need to use lcd.print instead of lcd.write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly which line you have edited but looking at your code it seems to me that the status String must be in double quotes. Also there should be , instead of . after "Awesomeness"

So instead of

```
String top[] = {'Status:', 'Adam:', 'Oliver:', 'Adam & Oliver:', 'Awesomeness'. 'OBEY:'};
```

You should have

```
String top[] = {"Status:", "Adam:", "Oliver:", "Adam & Oliver:", "Awesomeness", "OBEY:"};
```